# Непосредственная загрузка значения в YMM, XMM

Tags: ассемблер

Возможно ли загрузить в регистр YMM, XMM значение непосредственно из кода, без применения констант? Вроде:
mov eax,$1234

Способы загрузки с применением vmovups, vbroadcastss мне известны.

Comment: https://question-it.com/questions/979432/asm-x86_64-avx-razlichija-registrov-xmm-i-ymm

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Невозможно. Такая команда была бы чрезмерно длинной и превышала бы лимит в 15 байт на одну команду.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно заполнить все четверти константой:

```
mov     eax,0xAABBCCDD
movd    xmm0,eax
pshufd  xmm0,xmm0,0
```